# Add new configuration provider to IConfiguration in Azure Function v2.0

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I have a .NET Core Azure Function v2.0 and I'd like to inject a custom configuration provider during startup; however, it doesn't look like the IWebJobsBuilder provides a way to do additional configuration during the initialization sequence. Am I missing something or is there really not a way to inject these settings?

Comment: You need to inject some `key` `value` settings from any json ? is that your requirement ?

Comment: Not quite - I'd like to bootstrap the KeyVault configuration provider during the startup sequence so that I can store my Storage Account and other trigger information in KeyVault instead of the azure function configuration. but … in theory - its the same thing - is it possible to add an additional Json provider?

Comment: added an answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible to add additional json provider. From your `startup` you can do like this. You can make use of the **AddJsonFile** method.

```
public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("secret.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```